# JavaScript is breaking on web page in Chrome, and page appears blank

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Apologies for the naivety in advance, but a non-coder here!

We are using a cloud-based dashboard via Chrome, and one of the pages in this dashboard appears completely blank. Strangely enough, on a different PC, the same page appears fine (Version of Chrome on both PCs is the same).

The best I could was check the Chrome Developers tab on the PC where page is blank, and found this error appearing:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Rfm.png)

Tried digging deeper into the error message as well, but couldn't get far. I would really appreciate any leads / pointers in the right direction!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run your code with non minified code, or add a debugging map to the js so chrome can show you the "original" line in the non minified code.

Comment: Shouldn't you contact whoever created the dashboard?

Comment: No offense, but @ChrisG got it right, arn't you supposed to call the peoples you paid to make this dashboard if they exist ? Else if it's on only one PC, just erase your cache, it could resolve the problem.

Comment: @xoxel did contact them first, but there's been no response from. I'm going to try out these steps you guys have mentioned!